# Filtered ngRepeat in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive which I use as a select box. I would like to have a search field to filter the select box items. I'm having trouble filtering my items using ngRepeat filter.

**Here is the directive template:**

```
<a class="{{classes}}" href="javascript:;">{{placeholder}} &nbsp; <i class="uk-icon-angle-down"></i></a>
<div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-medium">
    <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-dropdown">
        <li ng-if="search" class="dropdown-input-wrap"><input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" class="dropdown-input"></li>
        <li ng-if="header && header.length" class="uk-nav-header">{{header}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items | filter:query"><a ng-class="{'selected': selected == i[property]}" ng-click="setVal(i)"  href="javascript:;"><i class="uk-icon uk-icon-user"></i>{{i.label}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The directive JS**

```
app.directive('lySelect', function($filter) {
return {
    retrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'partials/elements.select.html',
    scope: {
        items: '=',
        header: '@',
        index: '@',
        lyModel: '=?',
        placeholder: '@'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.setVal = function(item){
            $scope.lyModel = item[$scope.property];
            $scope.placeholder = item[$scope.label];
            $scope.selected = item[$scope.property];
            $scope.$emit('selectChange', {handle: $scope.handle, value: item[$scope.property]});
        };
    }],
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.query = '';
        scope.handle = attrs.handle;
        scope.search = attrs.search || false;
        scope.classes = attrs.classes;
        scope.property = attrs.property || 'value';
        scope.label = attrs.label || 'label';
        scope.selected = attrs.selected || "";
        var ph = $filter('filter')(scope.items, {value: attrs.selected})[0];
        scope.placeholder = ph[scope.label];
    }
}
});
```

**And I call my directive like this:**

```
<li class="uk-parent" search="true" ly-select ly-model="category" header="Categories" selected="{{category}}" items="categories" handle="categoryChange" data-uk-dropdown="{mode: 'click'}"></li>
```

Basically, if I set the `$scope.query` to something in the linker, it shows the list filtered, but after that, the filter is not working, well actually I think it is, but the view does not update. How come ? Should I update the view manually inside a directive ?

Thanks

Comment: How about binding the query to the scope of your directive too? Does it work?

Comment: How do you mean ? I do have `scope.query = '';` in my linker... And the ng-model in the template will map to my directive's scope right ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Can you check the console? Is there any error there?

Comment: No error, no info no...